# jQuery css syntax - definition

Tags: jquery, syntax

What does following syntax mean?

```
$(‘#somediv’).css({‘height’: vh + ‘px’});
```

Does it mean that if browser supports **vh** it will use **vh** as dimension otherwise it will use **px**?

What does +(plus) mean?

Comment: Read up on string concatenation please, along with the jQuery documentation

Comment: This is a realy basic basic question !!! You must start to read a documentation for developer... The plus char is used to concatenate two strings or add two integer values (this applies to JavaScript!)

Comment: `+(plus)` is unary conversion to a `number`.

Comment: Thanks a lot to everyone how answered my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably vh is "vertical height", is a string or numerical variable.

If vh is `"100"` or `100` the result is "100px".

Answer (score 4):

`vh` is a variable declaration, and was concat with `px`, px is a string

Comment: vh is a dimension for viewport, it's quite useful but IE8 doesn't support it.

Comment: @AlexF correct but and wrong here - vh is a variable, not a string

Comment: Yeah, could be like that, but for some reason, `vh` in the post is a variable holding some values.

Answer (score 1):

As per your code ,
css attribute has been applied(i.e. height) 
Where as the vh(vertical height) is a variable which is concaniated with px(pixel)

It doesn't mean browser supports vh it will use vh as dimension otherwise it will use px